# Using LazyHorizontalGrid inside LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

I try to use LazyHorizontalGrid with 2 fixed rows inside a LazyColumn. But then  app crashes:

`IllegalArgumentException: LazyHorizontalGrid's height should be bound by parent`

This is surprising, as I can use LazyRow inside a LazyColumn without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `LazyColumn` wraps the height of the content and can be stretched and in this way the `item` scope has `constraints.maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity`. The sum of the rows' height in the  `LazyHorizontalGrid` can't be `Constraints.Infinity`. It is the reason of the issue.

You have to assign a **max** `height` to your `LazyHorizontalGrid`.

```
LazyColumn {

    item {           
        LazyHorizontalGrid(
            rows = GridCells.Fixed(3),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.heightIn(max = 200.dp)
        ) {
            // item content
        }
    }
    items(itemsList) {
        item content
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot calculate height of LazyHorizontalGrid. And when I set a large max height (e.g. 2000.dp), LazyHorizontalGrid fills all that height. Still I don't understand, logically, what is the difference between 1 row (LazyRow) and multiple rows (LazyHorizontalGrid).

Comment: @mrzbn the `LazyHorizontalGrid` can't work in a container with `constraints.maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity`. The same happens with a scrollable Column. You can find the requirement here: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/LazyGridDsl.kt#L191